# Crop canvas to photo content in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

Is there a way to crop an image in Photoshop to the content and not the canvas size? I already removed the background of the image to make a cut out of the subject.

[image]

Now I'd like to trim away the canvas so that when I lay it out in InDesign, the text wraps around the person, not the whole rectangular image, which is what it does now.

[image: image with text wrap.]

As you can see, it's wrapping to the whole canvas, not just the figure.
I already tried Trim>Transparent Pixels, which didn't help.

Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: Raster images can only be rectangular - there is no way to remove the canvas either in Photohsop or any raster image editing software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to create a non-rectangular image in Photoshop.

In InDesign, you want to use the **Text Wrap** feature. This will allow you to wrap text based upon the *transparency* in the photo rather than the canvas rectangle. You merely need to ensure they Photoshop file has transparency around the edge, or the area you don't want shown. (White wont' work. It has to be transparent).

Place the image into Indesign and with it selected, click the "wrap" icon on the **Text Wrap Panel** and then set the **Type** to "Alpha Channel"

[image]

That will read the transparency and wrap text to it:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly–didn't know about Alpha Channel. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Also notice the thin blue line around the image in InDesign. That's the text wrap line. You can use the Direct Selection or Pen Tools to alter that line to manually change the text wrap as well.

Comment: When I export a transparent .png it is non rectangular and text wraps correctly.

Comment: **All** images are rectangular. I understand that transparency may make it *seem* like an image isn't rectangular. But rest assured there's really no such thing as a non rectangular image.

Comment: +1.  I use text wrap all of the time with images with transparent backgrounds, but have always manually edited the text wrap line.  I am thrilled to learn about text wrap based on the Alpha Channel!